# Datamapper + Carrierwave store method not being called, only cache

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, carrierwave

I have a really simple sinatra app which uses datamapper and carrierwave.

I've reduced the uploader to its minimum:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file
end
```

And have one simple model that uses it:

```
class Photo
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :caption, String
  property :position, Integer
  property :created_at, DateTime
  property :updated_at, DateTime

  mount_uploader :source, PhotoUploader

  belongs_to :album
end
```

It happens that when I use it:

```
post '/admin/album/:id/photo/create' do
  album = Album.get(params[:id])
  photo = Photo.create(params[:photo])
  album.photos << photo
  album.save!

  redirect '/admin/album'
end
```

`photo` is being created normally on the database and the file is being uploaded normally to the cache directory but not being moved to the final storage destination.

I've got into the carrierwave code and could verify that the `cache!` method is being called but not the `store!` method.

I've tried to use the uploader without any association to the object:

```
get '/lorem' do
  f = File.open('test.png')
  u = PhotoUploader.new
  u.store!(f)

  "ok"
end
```

Everything works as expected in this case.

**==================== UPDATE ====================**

I belive I've found the source of the problem. While running debugger I got to this:

```
gems/dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/query.rb:1014
conditions.each do |condition|
(rdb:1) 
gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:290
def sanitize(name)
(rdb:4) 
gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:299
def split_extension(filename)
(rdb:4) 
gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:29
self.file = file
(rdb:4) 
gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:269
if file.is_a?(Hash)
(rdb:4) 
gems/carrierwave-0.6.2/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb:274
@file = file

(rdb:4) pp file
"/Users/jvalente/Projects/dummy/public/uploads/{:filename=>\"Screen Shot 2013-01-24 at 4.57.15 PM.png\", :type=>\"image/png\", :name=>\"photo[source]\", :tempfile=>#<File:/var/folders/jp/wm1gxk8558d36rh9vzkmx4jw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130128-27245-105ybbf>, :head=>\"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\\\"photo[source]\\\"; filename=\\\"Screen Shot 2013-01-24 at 4.57.15 PM.png\\\"\\r\\nContent-Type: image/png\\r\\n\"}"
```

This clearly is wrong since it will fail the `file.is_a?(Hash)` condition and get into:

```
@file = file
@original_filename = nil
@content_type = nil
```

Still, I can't understand why this happens.